# Among object detection frameworks which is better in case of time, accuracy, object detection and prediction

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, resnet, imagenet

Need to start an object detection project. can anyone suggest the better framework which has better accuracy and speed. I have read about imagenet, resnet, mobilenet, yolo, tensorflow and dlib features. Can anyone give a comparison of them and suggest a better option.

Comment: your question is too broad, off-topic and given that you did not provide any specific requirements absolutely pointless. we get countless of "recommend the best" posts here. all have in common that the authors don't realize that they have to provide a measure for "good" and countless constraints. a Ferrari might be the fastest car on a race track but definetly not off-road... your project won't succeed just by using the "best", whatever this is supposed to mean. try to understand this befor working on anything else. your general understanding is absolutely insufficient. Please read [ask]

Comment: Sorry for the broad question. I just need to start with an object detection framework. I have googled with my requirement and found many frameworks which is said to be better in one way or other. Just I need a suggestion on which framework is better with a comparison of performance of them.

Comment: performance in what on which platform? it always depends on the circumstances...

Comment: Working with ubuntu and python. Need to find objects present in number of images I have with more accuracy, speed, classification, prediction and complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good overview is described in "*Speed/accuracy trade-offs for modern convolutional object detectors*" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.10012).

In order to save time, you may consider using Google Object Detection API https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection,  they have an tutorial on how to train on your own dataset.

It is hard to say which object detection framework is the best. However, I saw people usually  stick to Faster R-CNN (for accuracies) and SSD or YOLOv2 (for speed).

Comment: Is yolo or mobilenet more faster.

Comment: MobileNet is just a feature extracting architecture. Given the same image size, MobileNet SSD runs faster than DarkNet-19 YOLOv2.

Comment: thanks for the information